# I can't create a report with an object datasource in Visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

I am trying to create a simple report in my vs2019 with a class as the data model

1. I have a public class named 'persona'
2. I have a new wpf applicacion (.net 5)
3. I've create a new report (RDLC file)
4. I try to use a class as a data template  to design the report
   When I try to reference the class as the data source object, the class is not visible for the datasourtce wizard  as you can see in the image below
   [image]

If put that class in a diferent project, a class library project, I got a different error, as you can see in the images below
[image]

And whe I press the Finish button I got this new erro:
[image]

There is no clue about what to do,...  does anyone have any idea ? What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. Try to use netstandard2.0 for model library, it works for me (vs2019 netcoreapp3.1)